# sudo pip install packagename not working

Tags: python, pi-2, opencv

sudo pip install packagename not working...
I am not able to install python package using pip.[image: sudo pip install packagename not working]

Comment: Have you tried installing Python using other means?

Comment: Do you have internet connection? Check this by `ping google.com`

Comment: Please do not post screendumps. Grab the output and post it (properly formatted) as text.

Comment: It is working now. @DarthVader

Comment: Could you post an answer explaining how you solved your problem and mark it as correct.

Comment: For proxy server it should be written in this format:
sudo pip --proxy yourProxyWithPort install packagename

Answer (score 1):

<sup><sub>[Per OP's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48246/sudo-pip-install-packagename-not-working#comment73810_48246):</sub></sup>

For proxy server it should be written in this format:

```
sudo pip --proxy yourProxyWithPort install packagename
```